# Where should we store the root object graph when you're developing a library?

Tags: android, dependency-injection

Normally when developing an Android application, you store your object graph (possibly a dagger component) in your application subclass.

```
val objectGraph = MySdk.Builder()
  .build
```

But in the context of an SDK (`android-library`), we don't have access to the application subclass.

This SDK will be responsible for launching certain activities. These activities will need access to the object graph. How can this be done without storing the graph statically?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is really the answer you want as it does "store the graph statically", but it might help none the less.

For the library I'm working on at the moment (for a client). We use a class such as the following to hold the object graph instead of a custom Application class:

```
public final class MySdk {

    private static ObjectGraph objectGraph;

    public MySdk(String clientKey, Application application) {

        objectGraph = new ObjectGraph();
        objectGraph.buildGraph(clientKey, application);

    }

    public static Authentication getAuthentication(){
        return getObjectGraph().get(Authentication.class);
    }

    private static ObjectGraph getObjectGraph(){

        if (objectGraph == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The constructor must be called first");
        }

        return objectGraph;
    }

}
```

Integrators wishing to use the library need to construct that class (usually in the onCreate of their own custom application class)

```
public class CustomApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        MySdk mySdk = new MySdk(BuildConfig.CLIENT_KEY, this);
    }
}
```

After that, the dependencies are available from anywhere as follows:

```
Authentication authentication = MySdk.getAuthentication();
```

(ObjectGraph is whatever you want of course, Dagger component or home grown. We didn't really want to put Dagger2 in the library so we use something like this at the moment: https://github.com/erdo/asaf-project/blob/master/example01databinding/src/main/java/foo/bar/example/asafdatabinding/ObjectGraph.java)